# angular protractor error - Failed: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:56018

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e, angular-test

I am doing e2e testing using protractor of one of my page and some time I get `Failed: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:56018` error.

Some time it also passes without any error. I have no clue whats going on!

The full error:

```
Failed: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:56018
Error: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:56018
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/pro1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:238:15)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)Error
at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/Users/pro1/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:482:23)
at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/Users/pro1/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:96:21)
at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/Users/pro1/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:873:14)
at /Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:107:37
at step (/Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:47:23)
at Object.next (/Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:28:53)
at fulfilled (/Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:19:58)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From asynchronous test:
    Error
at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:62:3)
at addSpecsToSuite (/Users/pro1/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1107:25)
at Env.describe (/Users/pro1/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1074:7)
at describe (/Users/pro1/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4399:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pro1/e2e/app/data-entity/sme/sme.e2e-spec.ts:30:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Module.m._compile (/Users/pro1/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:392:23)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/pro1/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when Protractor cannot connect to your local Selenium Server. If you are sure your Selenium Server is running on port 56018, then you may be having network issues that are not associated with Protractor. In your **spec.conf.js** file, I would update to use the default *4444* port, for both Selenium and Protractor for testing purposes.

```
// spec.conf.js file
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
    ...
}

// Command-line: Selenium through Protractor's webdriver-manager
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start

// Command-line: Selenium through standalone
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444
```

Comment: after updating `seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"` still getting the same issue

Comment: You need to change both the **spec.conf.js** file configuration and the actual Selenium Server configuration that is done depending how you start the server. I gave two examples above.

Comment: `// Command-line: Selenium through Protractor's webdriver-manager
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start` I have followed this approach and made changed as you suggested

Comment: When you run **webdriver-manager start** it should tell you what port it is running on. It should be 4444.

    14:32:21.597 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

Comment: yes, `server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -port 4444
[16:57:30] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 10132
`

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when selenium server is not able to start or Protractor cannot connect to your local Selenium Server.
Well if you are testing your App with Google Chrome, you can use

```
// spec.conf.js file
exports.config = {
    directConnect:true
}
```

in your conf.js file. It will ignore all selenium server settings. And will start your test with chrome drivers directly.